# JavaScript: Make and Filter/Create Date wise array of object. i.e. skype chat history view

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have been trying this from the last couple of hours and I have searched a lot but couldn't find any solutions I am fetching data from the DB and there is the timestamp.

I want to filter records datewise i.e. if there is data of 2020-08-20 date then create an object then set all that days data in one object.

An object that I am fetching:

```
[
    {
        "id": 16,
        "activity": "Amazon 16",
        "type": "delivery_arrival",
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "created_at": "2020-08-25T12:14:13.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-08-25T12:14:13.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "activity": "Amazon 15",
        "type": "delivery_arrival",
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "created_at": "2020-08-25T12:14:10.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-08-25T12:14:10.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "activity": "Amazon 14",
        "type": "delivery_arrival",
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "created_at": "2020-08-25T12:14:07.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-08-25T12:14:07.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "activity": "Amazon 13",
        "type": "delivery_arrival",
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "created_at": "2020-08-25T12:14:03.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-08-25T12:14:03.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "activity": "Amazon 12",
        "type": "delivery_arrival",
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "created_at": "2020-08-25T12:13:59.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-08-25T12:13:59.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "activity": "Amazon 11",
        "type": "delivery_arrival",
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "created_at": "2020-08-25T12:13:51.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-08-25T12:13:51.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "activity": "Amazon 10",
        "type": "delivery_arrival",
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "created_at": "2020-08-25T12:13:46.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-08-25T12:13:46.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "activity": "Amazon 9",
        "type": "delivery_arrival",
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "created_at": "2020-08-25T12:13:40.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-08-25T12:13:40.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "activity": "Amazon 8",
        "type": "delivery_arrival",
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "created_at": "2020-08-25T12:13:33.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-08-25T12:13:33.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "activity": "Amazon 7",
        "type": "delivery_arrival",
        "url": "www.google.com",
        "created_at": "2020-08-25T12:13:30.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-08-25T12:13:30.000Z"
    }
]
```

What I want is:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2020-08-20",
        "activities": [
            {
                "activity": "name1"
            },
            {
                "activity": "name2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2020-08-19",
        "activities": [
            {
                "activity": "name1"
            },
            {
                "activity": "name2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Also, there is paginations and data has to be in descending.

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://momentjs.com/ and a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`is between`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/)
and then a [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with [`is after`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/); I'll also recommend [Ramda's Group By](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupBy) (and if you already are there, the filter and sort from Ramda are immutable, the sort of Array.prototype.sort isn't)

Comment: Is there any way to do a native way? an example would be very helpfull. @Coding Edger

Answer (score 0):

```
 var ParshedArray = {}
    var dates = []
    result.forEach(function (row) {
        var a = row.date.getFullYear()
        var b = row.date.getMonth()+1
        var c = row.date.getDate()
        var d = a+"-"+b+"-"+c
        console.log(d)
        var objDate = ParshedArray[d]
        if (!objDate) {
            objDate = {
                Date: d,
                Massages: []
            }

            ParshedArray[row.date] = objDate
            dates.push(objDate)
        }

        objDate.Massages.push({
            id: row.id,
            text: row.text,
            date: row.date
        })
    })
console.log(dates)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.